# Inefficiency concerns with Z3 solver

Tags: z3, solver, smt

As part of a static-time compiler analysis, I am using (the Java API of) Z3 solver to check whether a system of (in)equations is satisfiable. Everything seems to work correctly. However, the solver is too slow. For the system posted below, Z3 takes about 109s to declare the system as unsatisfiable.
I do not have any prior experience with Z3. Are there any rule of thumbs to follow in order to help the solver be reasonably efficient?

The set of (in)equations in prefix form are as follows:
*(Note: ITE represents if-then-else, and takes three operands.)*

```
[ < , i_imopVarPre1,  ITE ,  > ,  - ,  + ,  + , 0,  * , tid2,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh, 100, 0, 100,  + ,  + , 0,  * , tid2,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh]
[ >= , i_imopVarPre1,  + , 0,  * , tid2,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh]
[ < , i_imopVarPre0,  ITE ,  > ,  - ,  + ,  + , 0,  * , tid1,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh, 100, 0, 100,  + ,  + , 0,  * , tid1,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh]
[ >= , i_imopVarPre0,  + , 0,  * , tid1,  + ,  / ,  - , 100, 0, numTh,  % ,  - , 100, 0, numTh]
[ = , i_imopVarPre0, i_imopVarPre1]
[ > , numTh, 0]
[ >= , tid2, 0]
[ < , tid2, numTh]
[ >= , tid1, 0]
[ < , tid1, numTh]
[ != , tid2, tid1]
```

I have declared all variables to be of Int sort.
After adding these expressions to Z3, when I print the assertions in the solver, I get the following output:

```
(let ((a!1 (+ (div (- 100 0) numTh) (mod (- 100 0) numTh))))
(let ((a!2 (> (- (+ 0 (* tid2 a!1) a!1) 100) 0)))
  (< i_imopVarPre1 (ite a!2 100 (+ 0 (* tid2 a!1) a!1)))))
(let ((a!1 (* tid2 (+ (div (- 100 0) numTh) (mod (- 100 0) numTh)))))    
  (>= i_imopVarPre1 (+ 0 a!1)))
(let ((a!1 (+ (div (- 100 0) numTh) (mod (- 100 0) numTh))))
(let ((a!2 (> (- (+ 0 (* tid1 a!1) a!1) 100) 0)))
  (< i_imopVarPre0 (ite a!2 100 (+ 0 (* tid1 a!1) a!1)))))
(let ((a!1 (* tid1 (+ (div (- 100 0) numTh) (mod (- 100 0) numTh)))))
  (>= i_imopVarPre0 (+ 0 a!1)))
(= i_imopVarPre0 i_imopVarPre1)
(> numTh 0)
(>= tid2 0)
(< tid2 numTh)
(>= tid1 0)
(< tid1 numTh)
(not (= tid2 tid1))
```

Also, please find the statistics obtained after the call to `check()` method here: https://pastebin.com/cKimtm7g

For the above system, is it expected for Z3 to take ~100s? If not, am I missing something?

1. Shall I create shorter (in)equations, wherever possible? Would that help?
2. Does the order in which we add constraints matter?

Any suggestions in this regard would be really helpful. The number of such queries might be in the order of hundreds.

Furthermore, are there ways to reuse Z3 queries, since many of them might be isomorphic? Since identifier names can be different, I feel that the task of memoization/search itself can be costly.

Comment: It's really hard to comment on this, without being able to replicate. StackOverflow is best when you can post things that people can recreate on their own. I'm noticing that you have `div`/`mod` terms, which will be hard to solve. Are you using `Int`'s or Bit-vectors? You might be able to use a custom tactic, but impossible to tell without knowing more details. If possible, please post something that people can run on their own. (A complete SMTLib file that we can directly feed to z3 would be the best.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the point about div/mod. After reducing the number of div/mod operators by making the analysis slightly imprecise, I am able to reduce the solver time to 17s. Another issue with the given system is that the variable numTh does not have an upper bound. When I use the upper bound as "11", the time reduces to 0.3s. (With numTh <= 64, the time takn is 2.5s.)
As I have mentioned in the post, all variables are of Int sort.
This module is part of a software which isn't released yet; hence, I was unable to share more details. Your comment did help me solve the issue, though. Thanks!

Comment: Within few days after the release, I should be able to edit the post with a tarball using which one can replicate the scenario to better diagnose the issue. Until then, thanks for your help. :)